# haskell recursive descent parser

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming, abstract-syntax-tree

How can i create a recursive decent parser without the use of parsec or any library, for this grammar?
The output should be an error message if the string does not belong in this  grammar?
parse::String -> AST

Re -> Sq | Sq + Re

Sq -> Ba | Ba Sq

Ba -> El | Ba*

El -> lower-or-digit | (Re)

lower-or-digit are just lowercase letters or digits

Comment: You can use `alex`, and `happy`: https://www.haskell.org/alex/ https://www.haskell.org/happy/

Comment: _Why_ do you not want to use any library?

Comment: *without the use of parsec or any library* - without saying why, this is an absurd requirement.

Comment: The nice thing about using libraries, is that typically you can focus more on the *what* than the *how*. Lexers and parsers tend to be rather "hard" to "wire yourself". So it is typically better to use a tool that prevents making mistakes.

Comment: To write a recursive descent parser, you first need to rewrite your grammar in LL(1) form. After that, you can write your top-down parser by checking the first character/token and selecting the right production. Libraries can do part of this for you, but you don't want to use them for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to define your abstract syntax tree, likely as some declared data types. Then you want to define your basic parsing action. For instance,

```
type ParseResult = Either String AST
type ParseState  = (ParseResult, String)
```

Your parse action is straightforward:

```
re, sq, ba, el :: ParseState -> ParseState
```

where `re` is the top level parser action.

The concrete parsing step might look like this:

```
el (_, ('(':restOfInput)) = case re (Right restOfInput) of
                             err@(Left error, s) -> err
                             (result, ')':s) -> (El result, s)
                             (_, s) -> (Left "no closing parens", s)
el (_, input@(c:restOfInput)) = if lowerOrDigit c 
                                then (El c, restOfInput) 
                                else (Left "bad character", "")
```

Where a parsing library buys you a lot of traction is in handling all of the parsing state and propagating errors up the call stack.